# How to populate null column values w/ next non-null value

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql, window-functions

I have an interactions table where each interaction has an id_agent assigned to it. Some rows have null values for the id_agent and I want to assign the next non-null value to it. I can do this with a lead function for the next row however, I have instances where there are multiple consecutive rows with id_agent as null

Current Data:

| id_agent | ts_end_utc | inbound_or_outbound | interaction_channel | id_ticket |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -2 | 2020-09-15 9:40:04 | Inbound | supportbot | 93789075 |
| 299210763 | 2020-10-10 16:00:23 | Outbound | messaging | 93789075 |
| Null | 2020-10-12 8:46:05 | Inbound | messaging | 93789075 |
| Null | 2020-10-12 10:38:07 | Inbound | messaging | 93789075 |
| Null | 2020-10-15 8:25:23 | Inbound | messaging | 93789075 |
| 234926893 | 2020-10-15 17:45:58 | Outbound | messaging | 93789075 |
| 299210763 | 2020-10-28 19:05:49 | Outbound | messaging | 93789075 |
| Null | 2020-11-09 6:50:13 | Inbound | messaging | 93789075 |
| 299210763 | 2020-11-09 13:03:05 | Outbound | messaging | 93789075 |

Desired State:

| id_agent | ts_end_utc | inbound_or_outbound | interaction_channel | id_ticket |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -2 | 2020-09-15 9:40:04 | Inbound | supportbot | 93789075 |
| 299210763 | 2020-10-10 16:00:23 | Outbound | messaging | 93789075 |
| 234926893 | 2020-10-12 8:46:05 | Inbound | messaging | 93789075 |
| 234926893 | 2020-10-12 10:38:07 | Inbound | messaging | 93789075 |
| 234926893 | 2020-10-15 8:25:23 | Inbound | messaging | 93789075 |
| 234926893 | 2020-10-15 17:45:58 | Outbound | messaging | 93789075 |
| 299210763 | 2020-10-28 19:05:49 | Outbound | messaging | 93789075 |
| 299210763 | 2020-11-09 6:50:13 | Inbound | messaging | 93789075 |
| 299210763 | 2020-11-09 13:03:05 | Outbound | messaging | 93789075 |

I know how I can later use a case statement to make the column look as desired but how would I setup the logic/function to take the next non-null value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `last_value()`:

```
select t.*,
       last_value(id_agent, true) over (order by ts_end_utc) as imputed_id_agent
from t;
```

Comment: I don't believe that last_value can take an argument 1

Comment: @HarryBarsegyan . . . You may need to use `true` instead.  For some reason, Hive supports this functionality but not the standard `ignore nulls` keyword that should implement it.

Comment: Another thing is that this isn’t the end of the data. It is a big dataset which continues and similar patterns keep coming about (I just edited the sample data) @gordonlinoff