# Populate the last no null value to the next null rows until the next available non null value in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, window-functions

I am having the input data as below and `new MD_flag` is the out column based on md_flag column vaue .

```
sellingseason|item|location|wk|md_flag|New md_flag
Q1-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|Mar W5-23|TRUE|TRUE
Q1-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|Apr W1-23|TRUE|TRUE
Q1-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|Apr W2-23|TRUE|TRUE
Q1-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|Apr W3-23|TRUE|TRUE
Q1-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|Apr W4-23|TRUE|TRUE
Q2-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|May W1-23|TRUE|TRUE
Q2-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|May W2-23|TRUE|TRUE
Q2-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|May W3-23|TRUE|TRUE
Q2-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|May W4-23|TRUE|TRUE
Q2-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|Jun W1-23|FALSE|FALSE
Q2-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|Jun W2-23|TRUE|TRUE
Q2-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|Jun W3-23|NULL|TRUE
Q2-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|Jun W4-23|TRUE|TRUE
Q2-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|Jun W5-23|NULL|TRUE
Q2-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|Jul W1-23|NULL|TRUE
Q2-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|Jul W2-23|FALSE|FALSE
Q2-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|Jul W3-23|NULL|FALSE
Q2-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|Jul W4-23|NULL|FALSE
Q3-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|Aug W1-23|NULL|FALSE
Q3-23|BP608WZ271812|LBDI|Aug W2-23|NULL|FALSE
```

The logic for `New md_flag` is when ever `Md_flag` is `Null` we need to populate the prior non null value until the next non null value .

I tried using the Hive windows function but not able to achieve the required logic .Can some one please help me with the logic .

I see a similar post in the community but correct answer is not provided .
[How to populate null column values w/ next non-null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68076166/how-to-populate-null-column-values-w-next-non-null-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WINDOW function `last_value` with another argument inside it as `TRUE` to ignore nulls as follows:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(md_flag,
                last_value(md_flag, true) 
                   over (partition by item, location order by wk) 
               )   as  md_flag
from your_table t
```